# Fetch 2 columns with linq and make a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I want to make a dropdown list based on values from 2 columns, `Id` and `Name`, so I want it to be like `<option value=Id">Name</option>`, not just Name.

I can get just the names like so which is fine:

```
var result = from r in db.Categories
                         select r.Name;

            ViewBag.Categories = result;

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories), "Select Category")
```

But I want to have both ids and names as I already said, so I change my linq to be:

```
var result = from r in db.Categories
                         select new { r.Name, r.Id };
```

But I don't know how to make a dropdown with it with both id and name?

Comment: `ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, new (SelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "Select Category")`

Comment: I get a red line under `(SelectList)` in the view saying it's a type which is not valid in current context.

Comment: Sorry - remove `new` in front of it

Comment: That;s it, thanks! Why not put this as the answer, this is important for newbies like me? Also, how would I loop thru that ViewBag in the view to get both the id and name out of it, if you dont mind?

Comment: What do you mean _loop thru that ViewBag_ - why would you want to do that? (and also refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o))

Comment: I think it's good to know. I mean if I assign the query result to the ViewBag as in the original, e.g. iewBag.Categories = result; and then go thru it in the view and get the id and name for each row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127523/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-frc).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom SelectList in your `Action` and put it in a `ViewBag` before returning the result.

```
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");
```

This will make a list for you based on `db.Categories` and put the values of the `Id` column into "value" and `Name` as textnode.
If you want to change the textnode, you'll need to create a custom list, e.g.:

```
List<Categorie> temp = db.Categories.ToList();
Foreach (var t in temp)
   t.Name = String.Format("{0} {1}", t.Id, t.Name);
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(temp, "Id", "Name");
```

Don't forget to parse the ViewBag into a SelectList when calling in a view.

```
@{
SelectList categories = ViewBag.Categories as SelectList;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, categories)
```